# "No Processes Defined" from foreman check on a simple node.js Procfile

Tags: windows, node.js, heroku, foreman

Using this example procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

I'm getting errors when running the command

```
foreman check
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR: no processes defined
```

Not sure if this matters, but I'm running this on Windows 8.  The application runs successively on my local machine running just:

```
node app.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Foreman [does not run on Windows](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/41). ddollar started up an alternate project, [foreman-windows](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/41), to try to add Windows support, but I don't know if it ever fully got off the ground.

If you'd like a helper task to start up your node environment locally, writing your own [cake](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html) task is good, albeit manual, alternative:

```
{spawn, exec} = require 'child_process'

task 'start', 'Spin up dev environment', ->
  exec 'node app.js'
```

Then you'd execute the task in the command line:

```
cake start
```

This gives you the added benefit of creating multiple tasks for various actions, and fine-tuning the tasks to fit the needs of your project.

Note that Windows likes to switch things up when it comes to certain commands. For instance, on *nix-based machines you could open your site in a browser with:

```
exec "open http://localhost:3000/"
```

But on Windows, it is `start` instead:

```
exec "start http://localhost:3000/"
```

Another important difference is handling environment variables. On *nix, you can simply prepend them to your command:

```
exec "NODE_ENV=staging node server.js"
```

But if you try to use that format with `exec` on Windows, it'll fail. Instead, spawn a new bash:

```
terminal = spawn 'bash'
terminal.stdin.write "NODE_ENV=staging node server.js"
terminal.stdin.end()
```

And you can listen for events from the bash too:

```
terminal.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
  console.log "#{data}"
terminal.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
  console.log "#{data}"
```

If you are writing tools that have to support multiple platforms, you can do a OS platform check relatively easily to make accommodations:

```
os = require 'os'

if os.platform() is 'win32'
  <do Windows stuff>
```